# How to give hdd space to ubuntu after dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

i had recently dual booted ubuntu 20.04 with my windows 10 and i alloted 35 gb to ubuntu.Both my operating systems are on ssd . Now i want to give some hdd space to ubuntu for storage purposes.How can i do this?

Comment: The simplest way would be to shrink your Windows partition *in Windows*, then use a Live USB/DVD for Ubuntu to expand your partition into the new space. There are a lot of answers on how to do this, [such as this one from 10 years ago](https://askubuntu.com/a/18525/1091774) 

Comment: Are you saying you have two drives, one SSD and one HDD? If so you probably need to shrink the Windows partition(s) that are on the HDD using Windows disk manager. Then you use GParted in Ubuntu to create and format a partition on the HDD for Ubuntu to use. Then you mount the new partition somewhere convenient and create a new entry in fstab to mount it again each time you boot. Happy to provide a more detailed process if this is the scenario

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that hdd is used by windows operating system right now(If you are adding new hdd then you can skip first step)

First we have to release the storage from windows side so that it won't harm our data from windows storage.

- From windows disk management right click on the hdd partition you want to allot to Ubuntu. For that follow this [link](https://www.ceofix.net/3193/how-to-shrink-volume-partition-in-windows-10/).

Second step

- Create a live USB of Ubuntu with same version you are running in dual boot.
- Boot from that live USB
- Open Gparted and follow these steps given in the [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/).

If you have any questions regarding this, you can ask in comments